# Seeing Version column in Access linked list

Tags: list, versioning, microsoft-access

I've turned on versioning for the list. It shows in the SharePoint List.

However when I link the list to my Access database the Version column isn't showing up. All the other columns do.

Thoughts?

[image: SharePoint View showing Version on]

[image: Access View showing Version not selectable column to display]